# SSIS using variable in Lookup Transform

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

In the Lookup Transformation , I specify a reference data set to use as follow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client_ID 
FROM     dbo.CLIENT
WHERE  (ENROLLMENT_DATE >='2016-07-01') AND (DE_ENROLLMENT_DATE <='2017-06-30')
```

If I want to replace the hard-coded `'2016-07-01'` and `'2017-06-30'`, does anyone know how I can do it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can always load your data to a stage table, then do a insert by T-SQL/Stored Procedure. Thus you have whole lot of flexibilities to do whatever you want to transform.

Answer (score 3):

You can use expressions to achieve this, just follow these steps:

1. Create two variable (ex `@[User::strBeginDate]` and `@[User::strEndDate]`) of type string
2. Mouse click on the `DataFlow Task` and press `F4` to show the properties Tab
3. On the properties Tab, Go to Expressions
4. You will find `[Lookup Transformation].SqlCommand`
5. Use the following expression

   ```
   "SELECT DISTINCT Client_ID 
   FROM     dbo.CLIENT
   WHERE  (ENROLLMENT_DATE >='" + @[User::strBeginDate] + "') AND (DE_ENROLLMENT_DATE <='" + @[User::strEndDate] + "')
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Before your Lookup Transformation add a Derived Column Transformation, in this create two new columns to get the month and year from a date variable. Like so:

[image]

In your lookup transformation use the following query:

```
SELECT 
  Client_ID
  ,YEAR(ENROLLMENT_DATE) AS ENROLLMENT_YEAR
  ,MONTH(ENROLLMENT_DATE) AS ENROLLMENT_MONTH
FROM CLIENT
```

Then in the Columns page of your Lookup Transformation wire up your query like so:

[image]

I don't think you need DISTINCT in your query because the Lookup Transformation just returns the first row that it finds.